# Does the VS2010 Parallel Patterns Library (PPL) parallel_for_each algorithm support std::set<>?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, concurrency, set, std

When trying the following code:

```
        Concurrency::concurrent_vector<int> results_temp;
        std::set<int > temp;

        Concurrency::parallel_for_each(temp.begin(), temp.end(),[&](int p) {
                results_temp.push_back(p);

        });
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\ppl.h(2081): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *'
```

I have managed to get parallel_for_each to work with `std::deque<>`, `std::list<>`, `std::vector<>`, and `std::map<>`. 
I am curious how to get it to work for `std::set<>` or why it would not be supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code compiled without error for me.

I added these includes:

```
#include <ppl.h>
#include <concurrent_vector.h>
```

Do you have SP1 installed?

Comment: I believe this is my problem. I have confirmed here: [Description of Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) that under '**Concurrency Runtime**' they list 'Associated containers can be used with the "parallel_for_each" function'. Once I get VS2010-SP1 installed I'll confirm that it works.

Comment: SP1 fixed this problem. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If you are using a later version of the Visual Studio IDE, but compiling with VS 2010, you still need to install the SP1 for VS2010. The updates for the later versions of VS will not install this Service Pack.

Answer (score 0):

If for whatever reason, there is no `Concurrency::concurrent_set`, then by all means use a 
`Concurrency::concurrent_map<T, unused_type>`

Ideally, `unused_type` would be filled in such a way, that `std::pair<T, unused_type>` could emply the empty base class optimization. Test and profile that. If it does, you are pretty much done.

<strike>Two</strike> four things

1. I know this is only slightly lame
2. assumption that `concurrent_map` has `std::map` semantics
3. minor assumption that `concurrent_map` uses pairs
4. I don't actually use PPL (I use [GNU libgomp with parallel mode](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/bk01pt03ch18s03.html#parallel_mode.using.prereq_flags))

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I am looking to change is: std::set<int > temp; and not Concurrency::concurrent_vector<int> results_temp; I am working around the problem by doing what you suggest: std::map<int,bool> where I mostly just ignore the bool.